# Import multiple txt files with different dimensions and different sizes of names as separated dataframes

Tags: r

I have 2 txt files named `In1B_HZM_VC_Suppl_astaxanthin.txt` and `In2B_HZM_VC_Suppl_beta-carotene.txt` with the following structure:

```
#txt1
Result1 GSK3B   SNCA    SOD2    APP NDUFS7  CAT KCNJ6   TNF PIK3R1  NOS2    EDN1    GSR NOS3    NDUFB6  CASP3
Result2 NDUFS8  NDUFS2  NDUFS3  ETFDH   NDUFV2  SDHA    SDHB    NDUFV1  NDUFS1  NDUFS7
Result3 COQ2

#txt2
Result1 DDR1    CXCL8   MMP1    PTGS2   RPS6KA5 TNNT2
Result2 NQO1    IL1B    CYP1A1  SP1 LEPR    TNF POR HMOX1   TP53    GRIN1   NFE2L2  GJA1
```

I'm trying to find a way to import these 2 files as separated dataframes since they are located in the same folder in my work directory.

I tried:

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/user/Documents/HZM/SourceDatasets", pattern = "*.txt", full.names = T)
```

which creates a list of their pattern and names

and then:

```
myfiles = lapply(files, read.delim)
```

or

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) assign(files[i], read.delim(files[i]))
```

or

```
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(files, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", files))), 
         read.delim), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

which give me an error message:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

I have also tried:

```
##Create list of data frame names without the ".csv" part 
names <-substr(files,44,68)

###Load all files
for(i in names){
  filepath <- file.path("C:/Users/user/Documents/HZM/SourceDatasets",paste(i,".txt",sep=""))
  assign(i, read.delim(filepath,
                       colClasses=c("character","factor",rep("numeric",4)),
                       sep = "\t"))
}
```

but my txt files have names with different sizes.

You can find the files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pn0xiw334ajg5ul/AADAOyok4LDr5kaeYzmIOHXFa?dl=0)

Comment: Why didn't `myfiles = lapply(files, read.delim)` work? maybe you need to pass more arguments to `read.delim`.

Comment: like what as you see the files

Comment: I attached them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have unequal columns for each row try using `read.table` with `header = FALSE` and `fill = TRUE`.

```
lapply(files, read.table, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
```

---

From the dropbox link I could read the files as

```
files <- list.files("/path/to/file/new/", full.names = TRUE)
files_list <- lapply(files, read.table, fill = TRUE)
lapply(files_list, function(x) x[1:2, 1:5])

#[[1]]
#       V1   V2    V3     V4    V5
#1 Result1 DDR1 CXCL8   MMP1 PTGS2
#2 Result2 NQO1  IL1B CYP1A1   SP1

#[[2]]
#       V1     V2   V3    V4   V5
#1 Result1 SCARB1 RXRA CASP3 ESR2
#2 Result2   BCO1
```

Comment: Im getting : 'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no lines available in input' when I give 'files' as input

Comment: @firmo23 I copied the same text as you have provided in 2 different txt files on my local system and read them using the exact same code and it worked for me giving me list of 2 dataframes with empty strings where there is no value present.

Comment: weird...why there is no value?

Comment: I attached the files

Comment: @firmo23 It still works for me. Check updated answer where I am showing 2 rows and 5 columns for both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what you wanted as output.  You just had a few lines, so I am assuming that you what the "names" in the files.  Try this:

```
> # define the data in the question
> txt1 <- "Result1 GSK3B   SNCA    SOD2    APP NDUFS7  CAT KCNJ6   TNF PIK3R1  NOS2    EDN1    GSR NOS3    NDUFB6  ..." ... [TRUNCATED] 

> txt2 <- "Result1 DDR1    CXCL8   MMP1    PTGS2   RPS6KA5 TNNT2
+ Result2 NQO1    IL1B    CYP1A1  SP1 LEPR    TNF POR HMOX1   TP53    GRIN1   NFE2L2  ..." ... [TRUNCATED] 

> # you did not say how you wanted the data.  If you only want to get the
> # character sequences, you can use:
> 
> all_names <- scan(text = c(txt1, txt2), what = '')
Read 49 items

> print(all_names)
 [1] "Result1" "GSK3B"   "SNCA"    "SOD2"    "APP"     "NDUFS7"  "CAT"     "KCNJ6"   "TNF"    
[10] "PIK3R1"  "NOS2"    "EDN1"    "GSR"     "NOS3"    "NDUFB6"  "CASP3"   "Result2" "NDUFS8" 
[19] "NDUFS2"  "NDUFS3"  "ETFDH"   "NDUFV2"  "SDHA"    "SDHB"    "NDUFV1"  "NDUFS1"  "NDUFS7" 
[28] "Result3" "COQ2"    "Result1" "DDR1"    "CXCL8"   "MMP1"    "PTGS2"   "RPS6KA5" "TNNT2"  
[37] "Result2" "NQO1"    "IL1B"    "CYP1A1"  "SP1"     "LEPR"    "TNF"     "POR"     "HMOX1"  
[46] "TP53"    "GRIN1"   "NFE2L2"  "GJA1"   

> cat("\nUnique combinations\n\n")

Unique combinations


> print(unique(all_names))
 [1] "Result1" "GSK3B"   "SNCA"    "SOD2"    "APP"     "NDUFS7"  "CAT"     "KCNJ6"   "TNF"    
[10] "PIK3R1"  "NOS2"    "EDN1"    "GSR"     "NOS3"    "NDUFB6"  "CASP3"   "Result2" "NDUFS8" 
[19] "NDUFS2"  "NDUFS3"  "ETFDH"   "NDUFV2"  "SDHA"    "SDHB"    "NDUFV1"  "NDUFS1"  "Result3"
[28] "COQ2"    "DDR1"    "CXCL8"   "MMP1"    "PTGS2"   "RPS6KA5" "TNNT2"   "NQO1"    "IL1B"   
[37] "CYP1A1"  "SP1"     "LEPR"    "POR"     "HMOX1"   "TP53"    "GRIN1"   "NFE2L2"  "GJA1"
```

Comment: I want 2 dataframes as output. my txts are in the same folder SourceDatasets and I am supposed to import them using the file path